# 位置情報サービスの利用許可設定後に再度アラートが表示される

Tags: swift, ios

位置情報を定期的に取得し、サーバへ送信するアプリを作成しています。
バックグラウンドでも継続して位置情報の取得を行いたいのでrequestalwaysauthorizationで位置情報サービスの利用許可を求めるアラートを表示させていますが、このアプリを使い始めて何日かすると、このアラートが再度表示されることがあります。

アンインストール→再インストールや、「位置情報とプライバシーのリセット」も行っていません。

requestalwaysauthorizationのアラートは位置情報サービスの利用許可がnotDeterminedになっている時のみ表示され、許可する・しないのいずれを選択しても以降は表示されなくなる認識なのですが、他にアラートが表示される条件があるのでしょうか。また、その場合のアラートの表示させる／させない、表示タイミングを変更するといった制御はできるのでしょうか。

開発環境
　Xcode8.2
　swift3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 8以降での位置情報サービスの仕様です。
https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT203033

バックグラウンドで位置情報を取得すると再度確認を行うダイアログが
表示されます。そのダイアログで許可していれば、アプリを再インストール
するまでダイアログは表示されなかったと思います。

確認ダイアログを再度表示しないようにするAPIもないようですし、App Storeや
アプリ上での説明で対応するしかないと思います。